# How to run gcc compiler from my qt application?

Tags: c++, qt, desktop-application

1- I am working on a project and i have made a simple GUI but i want to make a run button in my GUI to compile and run c code ??
(i want to make simple ide so i used qt to make my ui but i can not make a button which send arg to windows terminal  )

2- How to have a good start with Qt (need a good tutorial)

Comment: Huh? This question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Your question is strange. I suppose that you want to run gcc compiler from your own application, don't you?

Comment: I think you a little off topic! But anyway i would advice you to look at this site : http://www.voidrealms.com/ and also the official Qt Documentation : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html

Comment: @AlexanderTrotsenko  that is it

Comment: and i want to know why my question looks strange ???!!!

Comment: @Ahmed Adel The question formulation is unclear. I would use _"How to run gcc compiler from my qt application?"_ instead.

Comment: thanx for your advice @AlexanderTrotsenko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run any program from **Qt5** and capture it's standard output using the `QProcess` class. The official documentation with examples is here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html

So what I would do then is simply make a GUI with 2 `QTextEdit` widgets, one for the code and one for the compile/run output. Documentation for `QTextEdit` is here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html

So the "compile and run" button would simply

1. Take content of upper `QTextEdit` into a temporary text file on disk. Documentation for `QFile` is here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html
2. Start **gcc** to complie the file using `QProcess` and capture the output in a string
3. Replace the content of the bottom `QTextEdit` with the output of the compilation.
4. Look at return code from `QProcess` to see if compilation was successful.
5. For successful build, simply invoke `QProcess` again, this time for the executable that was built by gcc to run the code, while appending any output to the bottom QTextEdit.

**NOTE:** As an exercise this is probably going to be fun and provide ample opportunity for learning, however I doubt this would be very useful on its own.

Good luck!